# CSS Showing Page 1 of 10 on the bottom of the page

Tags: css

Trying to get **Page 1 of 10** showing at the bottom of the page when it is printed...

**Page 1 of 0** is showing so counter(pages) does not seem to be working. 
I am using Chrome so @pages { ... does not work either. Any idea's?

```
.custom-footer-page-number:after {
    content: counter(page) " of " counter(pages);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is never gonna work with Chrome. Try firefox old version, But not sure. Because this is no longer supported by major browsers :(.
But your code will work with weasyprint `http://weasyprint.org` and also princexml `http://www.princexml.com/doc/9.0/page-numbers/.`